# VBA 64-bit Excel not passing pointers to DLL functions (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, excel, vba, dll

I have VBA program running on Excel 64-bit calling some DLL functions (C++). The problem is (apparently) it can't pass pointers to C++ program. The program works with Excel 32-bit.The operating system is **Windows 8**. For  Windows 7 both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Excel are working well.

C++ :

```
double test(long* v, long i) 
 {
    if (v == NULL)
        return -88;
    else
        return *((long*)v);
 }
```

VBA:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function hamid_test Lib "...\CVode.dll" (ByVal v As LongPtr, ByVal i As Long) As Double

 Dim x As LongLong
 Dim z As Double
 z = test(x, 1)
```

It returns `-88`.

Comment: Try `Dim x As LongPtr`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim x As LongPtr
Dim z As Double
z = test(x, CLng(1))
```

`LongPtr` evaluates to `Long` in 32-Bit environments and to `LongLong` in 64-Bit environments so defining x as such should work.

Addtionally, `CLng` will ensure 1 is evaluated as a `Long` type. If this is not added VBA will assume you mean `Integer`